# Linked List sorting error

Tags: python, linked-list, bubble-sort

This code is supposed to sort through a list of 6 elements, ignoring the first. For some reason, I always get an error stating "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable". If anyone could offer me a solution or explain a fix to me that would be much appreciated.

```
def bubbleSortLinkedList(aLinkedList):
    pointer = aLinkedList
    swapped = True
    while swapped:
        pointer = aLinkedList['next']
        swapped = False
        for i in range(4):
            if pointer['data'] > pointer['next']['data']:
                pointer['data'], pointer['next']['data'] = pointer['next']['data'], pointer['data']
                swapped = True
            pointer = pointer['next']
        aLinkedList = pointer 
    return aLinkedList
```

Comment: Please also mention the content of your list

Comment: I bet the error is in this line: `if pointer['data'] > pointer['next']['data']:`. If any of the elements' `next` property points to `None`, there's your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last line of the while loop, you have written `aLinkedList = pointer`, which was pointing the list to the last element. However, what you intended to do was to set the pointer to the first element of the list.

This is the corrected code:

```
def bubbleSortLinkedList(aLinkedList):
    pointer = aLinkedList
    swapped = True
    while swapped:
       pointer = aLinkedList['next']
       swapped = False
       for i in range(4):
           if pointer['data'] > pointer['next']['data']:
               pointer['data'], pointer['next']['data'] = pointer['next']['data'], pointer['data']
               swapped = True
            pointer = pointer['next']

        pointer = aLinkedList # This line was wrong!!!!! 

    return aLinkedList
```